# please help with the following validation rule

Tags: validation-rule

Please add a validation rule to `User` that validates the value of `X2015_Costing_Group__c` to be one of the values currently listed in the picklist for this field.

Comment: Is X2015_Costing_Group__c a text field ? that should check to see if the value is same as one of the values from a picklist field ?

Comment: X2015_Costing_Group__c is of type picklist

Comment: I don't know of any [formula function](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions.htm&language=en_US) that you can use to get the possible values of the picklist. Hardcoding all the possible values in the formula would be one option. You could implement it in a trigger by doing a [describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describeSObject.htm) on the field

Comment: That's a ticket assigned to me by my manager and I'm an intern working for the very first time on salesforce he asked me to do it in sb4

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the requirement, but he wants you to make sure the picklist value is one of the possible picklist values? This is already implemented in the definition of a picklist, I think he or you may be accidentally omitting some information....

Comment: A picklist value can be set to any value if the data is pushed in via an API

Comment: Please add a validation rule to User that validates the value of X2015_Costing_Group__c to be one of the values currently listed in the picklist for this field.   (I will eventually be editing this rule to restrict adding users to certain costing groups)   

thats the exact thing that he sent me

Comment: @BarCotter ah you're right, good catch...Savith, list the possible picklist values here if you want to do this as a formula (as BarCotter said, you can explicitly code them in)

Comment: Business Desk 
CDG 
Central Services 
Education 
GSC - " " 
International 
Marketing 
N/A 
POIM 
TG


these are the picklist values

Answer (score 2):

The formula will look like this, the OR operator will return true if the picklist is any of the values 1-5, so the NOT operator will throw an error if it's **not** one of the specified values.

```
NOT(
  OR(
    ISPICKVAL(X2015_Costing_Group__c, 'value1'),
    ISPICKVAL(X2015_Costing_Group__c, 'value2'),
    ISPICKVAL(X2015_Costing_Group__c, 'value3'),
    ISPICKVAL(X2015_Costing_Group__c, 'value4'),
    ISPICKVAL(X2015_Costing_Group__c, 'value5')
  )
)
```

Comment: so I need to mention each fields name in the value place right? I never knew it works exactly like java's logical operator stuff. Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to tell from your comment, but it looks like you may have six possible values? Just add an ISPICKVAL condition for each value, and put the literal string value in the second parameter of that condition